# Conversion of Vissim files to SUMO

Tags: sumo

I am trying to convert vissim files to SUMO files using tls_vissimXML2SUMOnet_update.py script but it gives me key error.

I tried the conversion using netconvert but not all of my connections are getting established.

```
netconvert --vissim-file=SIM_K513V13.inpx --output-file=MySUMOFile.net.xml
```

This code gives the result as follows:

```
Warning: Could not set connection between '5_1' and '4_0'.
Warning: 1 of 8 connections could not be assigned.
Success.
```

I tried

```
./tls_vissimXML2SUMOnet_update.py -V SIM_K513V13.inpx -S MySUMOFile.net.xml -o SUMO_TLS
```

I got the result as:

```
Namespace(SUMO_net='MySUMOFile.net.xml', output_file='SUMO_TLS', vissim_input='SIM_K513V13.inpx') 


---

* loading VISSIM net:
     SIM_K513V13.inpx

---

* loading SUMO net:
     MySUMOFile.net.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tls_vissimXML2SUMOnet_update.py", line 557, in <module>
    conn_link_d)
  File "./tls_vissimXML2SUMOnet_update.py", line 294, in get_sg_connection_data
    conn_link_d[link] if conn[-1] == lane])]
KeyError: u'10007'
```

Could someone please help me with the conversion.

Comment: Can you share your input file?

Comment: @Michael https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IhXNNFdA7V3zD-TtVRt-8ZdIOW8Cqd9rbp-PBlEFpgQ/edit?usp=sharing 
Link of the input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in SUMO. I opened a ticket: https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/5560. Can we use the network under the EPL license for regression testing?
PS: The ticket is fixed now.